# How to integrate WebJARs into Adobe CQ 5.6.1?

Tags: maven, servlets, adobe, aem, webjars

WebJARs are a way to avoid having to get the script(s) locally stored in your codebase and integrate your favorite frameworks automatically via Maven. We're using the Adobe CQ platform and we're recently exploring how to integrate WebJARs into our code.

I've done this previously but not on CQ (I was using it alongside a JBoss server before, and it was working fine as expected). [Setting up WebJARs for use](http://www.webjars.org/documentation#servlet3) is pretty easy, i.e., just add below to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.6</version>
</dependency>
```

and then it can already be accessed like, /webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css.

My problem now is that when I'm trying it out already on my CQ server, the said resource can't be found. The browser console indicates that *the resource cannot be found (Error 404)*. Has anyone already experienced using WebJARs with CQ, for any leads?

Comment: I don't think it can be done just by adding a dependency. In CQ, the clientlibs are basically processed resources of nt:file. So I think you need to unpack the web jars and copy their contents into the resulting content package (→ on maven package). This sounds like a nice github project for a maven plugin. :)

Comment: Thanks @FlorianSalihovic! I had been having hunches about this one too but unfortunately, I can't confirm it with similar cases since it seems there's not a lot who has done a CQ+WebJars usage combo -_- sigh. It does seem interesting, how you put it. When I get to have some extra time I'd probably update you here on a solution if I come up with something too :-)

Comment: That would be awesome. I think the client lib approach is ok, but it could be way nicer. Using web jars would make things definitely easier and cleaner. Cheers